# Should I use the file system asynchronously when responding http requests?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple backend that takes a js object from a POST request and saves it to a JSON file.

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const form= {name, surname, email, message}; //some object
    try {
        let forms;
        fs.readFile('./files/forms.json', {encoding: 'utf8'}, (err, str) => {
            if (err) {
                //Handle ENOENT: no such file or directory.
                if (error.code !== 'ENOENT') throw error; //If not ENOENT, rethrow.
                fs.appendFile('./files/forms.json', '', 'utf8', (err) => {if (err) throw err;});
                forms= [];
            } else {
                forms= JSON.parse(str);
            }
            forms.push(form);
        });
        fs.writeFile('./files/forms.json', JSON.stringify(forms), (err) => {if (err) throw err;});
        res.end();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({err: "The message was received but was not saved."});
    }
});
```

I was wondering if the calls to the file system could block node's event loop, and therefore prevent it from responding to other incoming requests. If this is the case, what should I do to prevent it?

(Btw any suggestions to improve my code are very appreciated)

Comment: You are using the asynchronous functions for file management already.  Only this `forms= JSON.parse(fs.readFile(/* */))` doesn't make any sense as it will not return anything.

Comment: If your application runs out of threads then further requests will have to be queued, obviously. Using async is a way to use fewer threads for greater overall capacity. But it’s not a direct 1-to-1 thing.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski you are correct. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @JohnWu nodejs is single-threaded

Comment: Does it make sense to send a successful response code if there are async operations that might still fail?

Comment: @zemaj Isnt 500 an error code?

Comment: Short answer is that no using synchronous processes in request A will not block request B.  Node is single threaded but uses an event loop. You will however, have a longer latency in responding to the client. However, using async processes that might fail after you have sent a response to the client should be done purposefully.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski These are the callback functions, so how are they asynchronous? In my understanding, the fs method runs until completion and then calls my function. Wouldn't that block the thread?

Comment: No, they won't. They will allow other requests to be made at the same time. They will block the main thread for a short amount of time when the files will be actually processed. Using sync variants will block the main thread until the files will be read/written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually using fs asynchronously which mean that the event loop won't be blocked

It would block the event loop if you used `fs.readFileSync``

Note that your example will not do what you expect

Since fs.readFile is asynchronous, the callback you provided will be called at a later time, and the next instructions of the current function will be processed immediately without waiting for your callback to be called

```
// this will proceed immediately before the fs.readFile callback is called which mean that in your case forms will be undefined
        forms.push(form);

// here again writeFile is asynchronous, the callback will be called at a later time
        fs.writeFile('./files/forms.json', JSON.stringify(forms), (err) => {if (err) throw err;});
// which means that in any case you will end you response even if there is an error that might be thrown later
        res.end();
```

What you probably want to do here is to put this part inside the callback

```js
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const form= {name, surname, email, message}; //some object
    try {
        let forms;
        fs.readFile('./files/forms.json', {encoding: 'utf8'}, (err, str) => {
            if (err) {
                //Handle ENOENT: no such file or directory.
                if (error.code !== 'ENOENT') {
                  res.status(500).send();
                  return;
                }
                fs.appendFile('./files/forms.json', JSON.stringify([form]), 'utf8', (err) => {
                  if (err) {
                    res.status(500).send();
                    return;
                  };
                  res.status(200).send();
                });
                return;
            }
          forms= JSON.parse(str);
          forms.push(form);
          fs.writeFile('./files/forms.json', JSON.stringify(forms), (err) => {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).send(...);
              return;
            }
            res.status(200).send()
          });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({err: "The message was received but was not saved."});
    }
});
```

As you can see all those nested callback is quite cumbersome, you can have a look at async/await syntax which may be more readable.

Also note that the errors you threw in your callback won't be propagated as you expect since the callback won't be running in the same stack call